# SSH no longer listens on custom port after update to 10.12.4

Tags: macos, ssh

I had a custom port by using the "Port" line in /etc/sshd_config.  After updating to Mac OS X 10.12.4 I found I could no longer connect on the custom port - instead it was listening on port 22.  I found that my sshd_config had apparently been renamed to sshd_config~previous, so I moved it back to the correct spot and restarted sshd from the command line using `sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd; sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd`.  However, after the restart sshd was still listening on port 22.  I then opened System Preferences and under sharing clicked on "Remote Login".  Running `netstat -a -n" showed that port 22 was no longer being listened to.  I then click on "Remote Login" to restart sshd, and then found sshd was still listening on port 22, not my custom port.

In /var/log/apache2 I see an empty `access_log` on startup, and `error_log` contains the normal startup message.  No clues there.

How do I get sshd to listen on my custom port again?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](http://zanshin.net/2015/10/01/change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/) and it appears to also apply for upgrading to Sierra from a pre-el capitan version of OS X.

To summarize:

```
sudo cp /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist
```

Edit /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist and change the lines that read:

```
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.openssh.sshd</string>
```

to:

```
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.openssh.sshd2</string>
```

And change the lines that read:

```
<key>SockServiceName</key>
<string>ssh</string>
```

by replacing "ssh" with whatever port you want to use.

Then start the new port with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist
```

As noted in the article, this doesn't eliminate ssh running on port 22.  In my case that was okay - the main reason for running on the new port was to match the port ssh was visible at outside the firewall.

Comment: To stop `sshd` answering on port 22, enter: `/usr/bin/sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`.